# Glmm models -> AIC model selection -> Several models have the same "explanationary power" (similar AIC) -> now what?

Tags: aic, glmm

So, I have a bunch of models, I'm using AIC for model selection, I don't have the exact numbers in front of me now but let's take for example:

- Model 1 - AIC = 100
- Model 2 - AIC = 101; $\Delta$AIC = 1
- Model 3 - AIC = 101,5; $\Delta$AIC = 1,5
- Model 4 - AIC = 103; $\Delta$AIC = 3
- Model 5 - AIC = 112; $\Delta$AIC =12

So i have been trying to figure out how to value these models. A lower AIC indicate a better model,

- $\Delta$AIC <2 tells me that the model has very strong support
- $\Delta$AIC 2 - 4  strong support
- $\Delta$AIC 4 - 10 weak support
- $\Delta$AIC >10 - no support

How should I interpret my result? Do model 1, model 2 and model 3 have exactly the same support to explain the data?

Or is model 1 still the strongest but I should discuss that model 2 and 3 also can explain the data?

How should I think when presenting this in my result and in my discussion?

Comment: You could build/report a best models table and/or also average models, in this case at the very least models 1, 2 and 3.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/316502)

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really a GLMM-specific question ... it depends a lot on context, of course, but I would say your second statement

> Or is model 1 still the strongest but I should discuss that model 2 and 3 also can explain the data?

is better.  If you want a more quantitative statement about relative strength of evidence you can use *AIC weights*, $w_i = \exp(-2 \Delta \textrm{AIC}_i)/\sum_j \exp(-2 \Delta \textrm{AIC}_j)$:

```
> daicvals <- c(0,1,1.5,3,12)
> ee <- exp(-2*daicvals)
> round(ee/sum(ee),3)
[1] 0.842 0.114 0.042 0.002 0.000
```

(the last value is not exactly zero - it's around $10^{-11}$). So you could say, for example, that the best model is about 8X more strongly supported than the next best.

IMO AIC weights don't have a very rigorous statistical foundation, but they are a useful and widely used heuristic.